# Set TTL for a column family in HBase using shell and using Java API

Tags: java, apache, hbase

I am new to HBase and I have searched at my end but I am unable to find a simple and straight forward way to set TTL attribute in a column family in HBase. Please specify both ways using shell and using Java API.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using the Java API:

```
HColumnDescriptor cfDescriptor = new HColumnDescriptor(Bytes.toBytes("cfName"));
cfDescriptor.setTimeToLive(20); // in seconds

tableDesc.addFamily(cfDescriptor);
admin.createTable(tableDesc);
```

And using shell:

```
alter ‘tableName′, NAME => ‘cfname′, TTL => 20
```

Answer (score 2):

modifying existing table to add TTL using Java API:

```
HConnection connection = HBaseConnection.createConnection("localhost", "2181");
            HBaseAdmin hBaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(connection);
            HTableDescriptor hTableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor("TTLDemo".getBytes());
            HColumnDescriptor hColumnDescriptor = new HColumnDescriptor("C".getBytes());
            hColumnDescriptor.setTimeToLive(2);
            hTableDescriptor.addFamily(hColumnDescriptor);
            hBaseAdmin.modifyTable("TTLDemo", hTableDescriptor);
```